# What happened to the "delete rejected" button in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom

In Lightroom CC 2015, where did they hide the *delete all rejected* button?

I want to easily mark all the real duds, those that are out of focus, accidental shots of feet, black frames, etc.  Marking (press X) is easy and doesn't require 3 layers of confirmation.

Then, review the marked files, and delete them. Now it prompts for "are you sure" and all that.

I recall there was a way to "delete all rejected" in the past, but now I can't find it.

Comment: What about filtering your pictures with the "rejected" filter ON ? Then select the ones you really want to delete and you are done :) (more info on how to do it here : http://laurashoe.com/2014/02/07/how-to-use-pick-and-reject-flags-to-sort-through-a-photo-shoot)

Answer (score 2):

Oliver's link contained the answer:

> Another way to accomplish the same thing without having to filter and select first, is to go up to Photo in the menu bar (top left of your Lightroom screen), and choose Delete Rejected Photos... This will take you to the same Remove / Delete from Disk dialog.

So, it's at the bottom of the Photo menu now (not the File menu).

I seem to have trouble seeing menu items when browsing through it... maybe because I work on photos after (real) work, after supper, when I'm tired of thinking; and the familiarity with older versions of the program make me expect to see things the older way.

Comment: Flagging photographs with `X` for rejection and then `Ctrl+Backspace` to confirm rejected photographs worked for me on Windows.